# How can I dynamically add a disabled attribute inside my EditorFor Template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, editorfor

I have a custom `EditorFor` template that I want to use for `DateTime` fields.  I want to be able to check if the user is in a certain role, and if they aren't, dynamically add a `disabled` attributed to the textbox.  I'm fully aware that I could check for this in my view and add the disabled attribute there.  However, I have roughly 20 `DateTime` fields and I don't want to check their role membership 20x if I can avoid it.  Therefore, I was hoping there was a way in my template to check if the user is an admin and add the attribute there.  Can this be done?

```
@model DateTime?

@if (Model != null)
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("", Model.Value.ToShortDateString(), ViewData)
    }
    else
    {
        /*Dynamically add disabled attribute here*/
    }
}
```

My View call:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Company.ActiveDate, "ShortDateTime", new {@class = "input-small has-date-picker"})
```

Comment: You also checking on server they can't change the date if they are in incorrect role?

Answer (score 1):

try adding this in your else

```
@Html.TextBox("", Model.Value.ToShortDateString(), ViewData, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: `Html.TextBox()` has no such overload?

Comment: I don't know what you are putting in the ViewData field.  when I build a Html.TextBox I have (name, value, html Attributes).  the html attributes is where you want to put the new disabled,  looking at options the 6th one might work for you (name, value, format, html attributes)